# Assigning a role in an action link

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do my best to avoid user error by embedding a method in an actionLink, so that when the user clicks "Merchant" or "Follower" it brings them to the Register screen where it is defaulted to assign them to the role that they clicked (merchant or follower), once they hit the submit button to register.  I am using UserIdentity framework to register.  Right now I could use a drop down box that allows the user to pick their role, but I feel like this will be allowing more user errors to occur.

```
    p class="lead">Register a @Html.ActionLink("Merchant", "Register", "Account") or Register as a @Html.ActionLink("Follower", "Register", "Account")</p>
```

So can I add another overload in the ActionLink to handle that?  If so what would the pseudo code look like?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Merchant", "Register", "Account", new { role = "Merchant" }, null)` and then add a parameter for `string role` to the `Register` method

Comment: Thanks I will give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: <p class="lead">Register a @Html.ActionLink("Merchant", "Register", "Account", new { role = "Merchant" }) or Register as a @Html.ActionLink("Follower", "Register", "Account")</p>

I used this and made the changes and the link is now broken.  Been trying to fix it.  Follower still works, but Merchant doesn't.  Is there an error here I am not seeing?

Comment: See my first comment - the last parameter needs to be `null` And did you change the method to `public ActionResult Register(string role)`?

Comment: Yep adding the last parameter did it.  Because I am still in school, can you tell me what adding the null parameter does?  I know what "null" is just not sure why it needs to be there for this to work.

Comment: You need to look at the various [overloads here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx). Without the last parameter, `new { role = "Merchant" }` was adding a html attribute, not a route value (if you inspected the html you would have seen `<a href="/Account/Register" role="Merchant" ...>` Adding the 5th parameter means you adding the role as a route value and adding `null` as the value for the html attributes (i.e it wont generate any). I'll add an answer shortly showing how to create the route as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller method to include a parameter for the role so that you can assign it to the model before you pass it to the view

```
public ActionResult Register(string role)
{
  var model = new RegisterModel
  {
    Role = role
  }
  return View(role);
}
```

Then modify the links to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Merchant", "Register", "Account", new { role = "Merchant" }, null)
```

which will now generate `/Account/Register?role=Merchant`. To generate `/Account/Register/Merchant`, you can define a specific route in the `RouteConfig.cs` file (ensure its the first one)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Register",
    url: "Account/Register/{role}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" }
);
```

Comment: I appreciate this.  Thanks!